# graphql + apollo приходят не те данные

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

Возникла такая проблема:

Когда я использую graphql playground (сайт для просмотра, создания запросов) мне приходят данные какие они и должны быть. Когда я запрашиваю данные c клиента в одном из объектов мне приходят не те данные, а именно свойство attributes.

Вот запрос с сайта playground:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот данные которые должны быть у объекта с id jacket-canada-goosee

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот описание запроса на клиенте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам запрос:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это тот самый объект в котором почему-то другие данные в атрибутах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы данные совпадали на клиенте с тем какие данные в playground.

И еще, проблема точно не в бэкенде. Это тестовое задание в одну компанию, я им должен предоставить только клиент. (тестовое задание не заключается в решении данного бага, возник этот баг только у меня). В консоли на клиенте данных больше, я просто для наглядности убрал в playground некоторые поля, проблема только с объектом attributes

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL хитрым образом кэширует данные. Так получилось что __typeName и id были одинаковые у предыдущего объекта и у объекта с id jacked.

Чтобы решить эту проблему нужно написать вот это, только вместо AttributeSet указать __typeName объекта в котором не те данные
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]